# How can you change the element drawing order depending on the datapoint index?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing several elements for each datapoint of the data I'm using in my d3.js datavizualisation. This creates a simple list of items, based on the data. It outputs the following:

```html
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 1]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 1]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 2]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 2]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 3]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 3]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 4]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 4]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 5]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 5]</svg>
</div>
```

For most people, this is exactly what they want.

However, what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to change the drawing order, for example, every even datapoint should start with the SVG tag and end with the p tag. Which would look like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 1]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 1]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 2]</svg>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 2]</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 3]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 3]</svg>
</div>
<div>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 4]</svg>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 4]</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>[Title of datapoint 5]</p>
  <svg>[SVG using datapoint 5]</svg>
</div>
```

*Notice that the drawing order has changed for both datapoint 2 and 4*

Can anyone tell me if d3.js offers a way to achieve this or can you tell me how you would fix this issue yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't share your code, so we cannot refactor it.

Therefore, I'll write an answer using `selection.each`, which is arguably the idiomatic D3 solution in your case. The only important thing here is passing the indices to the remainder operator, as `i % 2`, which returns `true` (`1`) for odd indices and `false` (`0`) for even indices. Then, using an `if`, we can chose which elements will be appended. For instance:

```
.each(function(_, i) {
    if (i % 2) {
        appendSvg(d3.select(this))
        appendParagraph(d3.select(this))
    } else {
        appendParagraph(d3.select(this))
        appendSvg(d3.select(this))
    }
});
```

In this case I'm using two different functions, to which I'm passing the current selection, but you can simply use the blocks you have (more repetitive code, though).

Here is the demo:

```js
const body = d3.select("body");

const divs = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .each(function(_, i) {
    if (i % 2) {
      appendSvg(d3.select(this))
      appendParagraph(d3.select(this))
    } else {
      appendParagraph(d3.select(this))
      appendSvg(d3.select(this))
    }
  });

function appendSvg(sel) {
  sel.append("svg")
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 20);
};

function appendParagraph(sel) {
  sel.append("p")
    .html("This is a p element")
};
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

svg {
  background-color: tan;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```